# Celery Crontab in not Picking the tasks

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery-beat

I have added crontab for every 1 minute in the celery beat schedule. Migrations also done properly. can I miss anything in this code ?Is the crontab format will be correct.
Thanks in advance . the crontab for minutes will work

```
settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'app1',
'django_celery_beat',
]
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'task-second': {
    'task': 'app1.tasks.elast',
    'schedule': crontab(minute=1),
}
}   

celery.py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')
app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


__init__.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)

tasks.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from proj.celery import app

@app.task
def elast():
    print("start")
    return "Exceuting after 1 minute"

celery beat worker:
celery -A proj beat --loglevel=debug --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler

logformat :
celery beat v5.1.2 (sun-harmonics) is starting.

[2021-07-27 11:07:00,894: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 seconds
[2021-07-27 11:07:00,916: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
[2021-07-27 11:07:05,931: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
[2021-07-27 11:07:05,932: DEBUG/MainProcess] Writing entries...
```

Comment: Are you also starting a worker? You need to have a beat scheduler process AND worker process(es).

Comment: yes i added worker also and it works properly for another tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
*'schedule': crontab(minute=1),*
```

into

```
'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
```

It should work.